# NgModel populates all input fields in login mask with password when password changes

Tags: angular

i am facing a strange behavior and have no explanation for it. The problem is the following: when a user inserts User and Password into a login prompt and something happens behind the scenes, the User field is also populated with the password the user entered. It looks like the form does not populates the fields correctly when it is re-rendered.

The code looks like the following (simplified for demonstration purposes):

LoginComponent.ts

```
public selModule = { AuthProps: [{Name: "User", Display: "DUser"}, {Name: "Password", Display: "DPassword"}] };
public loginData: { [key: string]: string } = {};

public changePW() {
    this.loginData['Password'] = "NewTestPw";
}
```

LoginComponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let authProp of selModule?.AuthProps">
        <label>{{ authProp.Display }}</label>
        <input [type]="handleInputType(authProp)" [(ngModel)]="loginData[authProp.Name]" name="authProp.Name">
</div>
<button (click)="changePw()">Change PW</button>
```

So if i type in username and password, both the input elements in the UI and the loginDate is populated correctly:

```
loginData: {User: "Testuser", Password: "Testpassword"}
User: Testuser
Password: TestPassword
```

By clicking on the button "Change PW" only loginData['Password'] is changed but the input field for the user is populated with "NewTestPW" as well.

```
loginData: {User: "Testuser", Password: "NewTestPW"}
User: NewTestPW
Password: NewTestPW
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: can you give code of changePw?

Comment: You can see it in the snippet of LoginComponents.ts. It just sets this.loginData['Password'] to a different value.

Comment: use `[name]="authProp.Name"` to make the attributte 'name' change too

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, because you have two way binded it with login data password, when you do that if loginData.Password will be changed, it will reflect in text box. If you don't want to behaviour change your

```
[(ngModel)]="loginData[authProp.Name]"
```

to

```
(change)="handleValue(authProp.Name, $event.target.value)"
```

in typescript

```
public handleValue(prop, value) {
     this.loginData[prop] = value;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so far! That means that the binding in this case was made to the loginData object and not to the attributes of this object? Is this explanation right?

Comment: no it was made to attributes, but it was two way. That means if you change value in input, attribute will get change. If you change attribute, input value will change. That's why its called two way binding.

Comment: Okay, i am aware of the concept of two-way binding. But then i still not understand why the input field that was two-way binded to loginData['User'] changes its value to the same value of the input field that was two-way binded to loginData['Password'].

Comment: what is in handleInputType()?

Comment: See this :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ajdgw. Its working fine. maybe some problem in handleInputType() ? can you show its code?

Comment: Yes i cannot reproduce it on stackblitz as well. I have removed handleInputType() but the behavior is still there. This might be an angular bug as the application is still on version 6.x.

Comment: no,its not angular bug. i can bet on it. its your code somewhere. i can give you same code on angular 6.

Comment: You were right. By creating an app from scratch it wasn't working as well since i had wrapped all of the code inside of a <form></form> element and this was causing the behavior. Removing the surrounding <form></form> element could solve the problem.